# Can I cook a food differently than the instruction?

Tags: frying

So the instruction on the food carton that I just bought only mentioned of oven-method but I actually know the food can be served via frying (on another brand product). 
Is it bad if I cook the food differently?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's hard to answer this without knowing the food, it would help get an answer if you edited and added more detail. Anyway, if you know you can cook it a different way why are you asking? More details there would be good as well.

Comment: @GdD I'm actually OK with there being a generic question about that. Many manufacturers suggest a specific method for finishing their prefab food, and it is not obvious whether one can always assume "if I can fry X, I can also fry this prefab X despite it not being mentioned on the package" or not.

Comment: what food are we talking about ? is the food uncooked/raw or cooked (i.e. only needs to be re-heated?)

Comment: anecdotal, I don't have a microwave oven, and I often re-heat frozen food in a pan.

Comment: There are two things to consider here. 1. will the result be tasteful? and 2. will the result be safe to eat? Neither can be answered without knowing what food exactly you are talking about.

Comment: Taken to extreme - you ***could*** deep-fry sponge cake. The result would be technically safe to eat, given adequate time to cook through thoroughly. The taste & texture, however, might not be all you'd desire in a sponge cake, especially if you used the same oil you'd just done your onion bhajis in ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can cook your food any way that you like, or is practical.  There are two issue to consider.  First, is the packaged product already fully cooked (and thus only needs reheating) or does it need to be fully cooked?  Your cooking or reheating procedure should be appropriate for this first distinction.  Secondly, if you use a cooking procedure different from the one specified on the package, your results might differ from the picture or the product's instructions.  However, as long as you cook or re-heat appropriately, the product will be safe to eat.

Comment: I regularly nuke foods that call for oven baking. Sometimes I just don't have the time to follow their instructions. It's hot, tastes essentially the same, but may not have the identical finished texture hat baking could produce.