# Can i cook a hash brown differently than the instruction?

Tags: frying

So in the package the instruction is only on an oven, but i know you can fry a hash brown.

Comment: are you the same user asking this question? https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/103015/can-i-cook-a-food-differently-than-the-instruction If so please ask a mod to merge your accounts and don't post the same question twice, you can always [edit] to add more details. Check [help] if you need more info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I cook a food differently than the instruction?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/103015/can-i-cook-a-food-differently-than-the-instruction)

Answer (score 1):

So long as the end result is cooked, you can do it however you like.
I'm assuming frozen, ready-made, supermarket hash browns [pretty much all you ever see in the UK]

- Oven bake - the lower-fat alternative, 220°C 15 - 20 mins. Nutrition content as stated on the pack.
- Shallow fry - medium heat, same total time, turn halfway through. More fat than the pack says. Good crisp & brown exterior.
- Deep fry - for when there's just not enough fat in your diet ;-) Probably ½ - ⅔ the time of shallow-frying. Should crisp up well without browning quite so much.
- Microwave - probably 1 - 2 mins, just check for when it's piping hot. Cooked, yes, but a texture like porridge.
- Dry fry or dutch oven - might work if you've patience & don't burn the bits that touch the surface before the heat reaches the rest. Wouldn't try this myself.

*& just to be silly - you could boil them… but really, no.*

Comment: Make a version of this video for supermarket hash browns. https://youtu.be/qWAagS_MANg